# Boolean similarity - is there a way to remove duplicates

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Given the following index

```
PUT /test_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
        "field1": { 
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "whitespace",
            "similarity": "boolean"
        },
        "field2": { 
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "whitespace",
            "similarity": "boolean"
        }
        }
    }
}
```

and the following data

```
POST /test_index/_bulk?refresh=true
{ "index" : {} }
{ "field1": "foo", "field2": "bar"}
{ "index" : {} }
{ "field1": "foo1 foo2", "field2": "bar1 bar2"}
{ "index" : {} }
{ "field1": "foo1 foo2 foo3", "field2": "bar1 bar2 bar3"}
```

for the given Boolean similarity query

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "size": 10,
    "min_score": 0.4,
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                "fuzzy":{
                    "field1":{
                        "value":"foo",
                        "fuzziness":"AUTO",
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "fuzzy":{
                    "field2":{
                        "value":"bar",
                        "fuzziness":"AUTO",
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            }
            ]
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm always receiving ["foo1 foo2 foo3", "bar1 bar2 bar3"] despite the fact that there is an exact result in index (the first one):

```
{
    "took": 114,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 3,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 3.9999998,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "bXw8eXUBCTtfNv84bNPr",
                "_score": 3.9999998,
                "_source": {
                    "field1": "foo1 foo2 foo3",
                    "field2": "bar1 bar2 bar3"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "test_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "bHw8eXUBCTtfNv84bNPr",
                "_score": 2.6666665,
                "_source": {
                    "field1": "foo1 foo2",
                    "field2": "bar1 bar2"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "test_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "a3w8eXUBCTtfNv84bNPr",
                "_score": 2.0,
                "_source": {
                    "field1": "foo",
                    "field2": "bar"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm aware of the fact that Boolean works that way to match as many results, and I know I can do rescoring here, but this is not an option since I don't know how many top N results to fetch.

Are there any other options here? Maybe to create my own similarity plugin based on Boolean similarity to remove duplicates and leave the best matched token, but I don't know where to start from, I see only samples for script and rescore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:- Based on the clarity provided in the comment section of my earlier answer, updating the answer.**

Below query returns the expected results

```
{
    "min_score": 0.4,
    "size":10,
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "fuzzy": {
                                "field1": {
                                    "value": "foo",
                                    "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                                    "boost": 0.5
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": { --> used for boosting the exact terms
                                "field1": {
                                    "value": "foo",
                                     "boost": 1.5 --> further boosting the exact match.
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And search results**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "zdMEvHUBlo4-1mHbtvNH",
                "_score": 2.0,
                "_source": {
                    "field1": "foo",
                    "field2": "bar"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "test_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "z9MEvHUBlo4-1mHbtvNH",
                "_score": 0.99999994,
                "_source": {
                    "field1": "foo1 foo2 foo3",
                    "field2": "bar1 bar2 bar3"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "test_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "ztMEvHUBlo4-1mHbtvNH",
                "_score": 0.6666666,
                "_source": {
                    "field1": "foo1 foo2",
                    "field2": "bar1 bar2"
                }
            }
        ]
```

**Another query without the explicit boost of the exact term also returns the expected results**

```
{
    "min_score": 0.4,
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "fuzzy": {
                                "field1": {
                                    "value": "foo",
                                    "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                                    "boost": 0.5
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "field1": {
                                    "value": "foo" --> notice there is no boost
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And search result**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "zdMEvHUBlo4-1mHbtvNH",
                "_score": 1.5,
                "_source": {
                    "field1": "foo",
                    "field2": "bar"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "test_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "z9MEvHUBlo4-1mHbtvNH",
                "_score": 0.99999994,
                "_source": {
                    "field1": "foo1 foo2 foo3",
                    "field2": "bar1 bar2 bar3"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "test_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "ztMEvHUBlo4-1mHbtvNH",
                "_score": 0.6666666,
                "_source": {
                    "field1": "foo1 foo2",
                    "field2": "bar1 bar2"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Because I want to perform a fuzzy query and not the exact one. Let's way I want some kind of "best Boolean" algorithm here, and each token to be matched at most once and not multiple times. In your example you have at least one exact match (this is what term query does AFAIK).

If I query for "foo" I want "foo" or "foo1", but sometimes I have foo1 twice (as in OP), and that foo1 is matched multiple times. But there is also an exact "foo" here.

Comment: @MagicWand thanks for your feedback, now its more clear to me, but I didn't get where in your OP foo1, came twice in the same field, it was in a different field, and correct me if I am wrong, you want to score high for a post which has precise `foo` even when that document contains just 1 times `foo` while other docs contains multiple `foo1`??

Comment: Yes, I was a bit unclear here, you are right. I want that score for 1 x precise "foo" is higher than 2 x "foo1" (or anything similar to "foo" that can be matched by a Boolean similarity).

Comment: @MagicWand, thanks for confirmation, let me think and work on this

Comment: @MagicWand, sorry for the delay, was busy in some other tasks, but good news is that I spent some time on this today and got it working :) , please have a look and provide your feedback

Comment: @MagicWand, Hope you are safe, please go through my updated answer and let me know if you have follow-up questions

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Elasticsearch Ninja! I thought to implement this algorithm in Elasticsearch directly by extending default Boolean similarity, but I did not find the samples (at least for newer versions of Elasticsearch).

Comment: @MagicWand first of all thanks for awarding the bounty :), IMHO you don't have to implement the simarlity yourself, as it can be easily worked out by tweaking the queries(mine is just one way but if you spend more time you will find many more :))

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still have doubts because of the score, which should fall into 0-100%, and I'm rescoring the score myself. I wonder how my scoring will behave when a combination of term and fuzzy matches are combined together. IMHO I will try to implement it myself in ES as a plugin directly, but that is a material for another post...

Comment: @MagicWand, yeah in this approach, the score wouldn't fall into 0-100%, but writing a plugin doesn't sound an easy task but please let me know if you are implementing it(would be new learning for me :))